# Lookup in subtables

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to lookup a table consisting of classes and corresponding number of students:

[image]

Given a number and a letter (e.g: `7`, `'C'`), I need a formula that determine # of students in the class given by them (e.g: class `7C`)? A formula like:

```js
=vlookup(A1, studentTableOf(B1), 2, 0)
```

Where `A1` is a cell containing the character `C` and `B1` contains the number `7` for example, and `studentTableOf()` is the function I am trying to figure out.

---

## What I tried

I tried restructuring my tables (at the cost of readability) which I think made the question more simple: applying `vlookup` twice in a multiple-keys table. But since it affect readability, I did not like setting up my tables like this.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the table approach that you mentioned trying. I feel that is far more elegant and efficient.

However if that is not possible then here is my solution given the data you've shared.

Use the formula in `K2` to get the # of students for the Grade mentioned in `I2` and the Class mentioned in `J2`

`=QUERY(ArrayFormula(SPLIT({(A1&"✦"&A2:A&"✦"&B2:B);(C1&"✦"&C2:C&"✦"&D2:D);(E1&"✦"&E2:E&"✦"&F2:F)}, "✦")), "select Col3 where Col1 = '"&CONCATENATE("Grade ", I2)&"' and Col2 = '"&J2&"' and Col3 is not null", 0)`

[image]

How it works:

1. Make a table (similar to the one you mentioned trying) by adding Grade names mentioned in `Row 1` against the Class name and the # of students for every grade. The part of the formula that does this is:
   `ArrayFormula(SPLIT({(A1&"✦"&A2:A&"✦"&B2:B);(C1&"✦"&C2:C&"✦"&D2:D);(E1&"✦"&E2:E&"✦"&F2:F)}, "✦"))`. If you add more Grades then you will have to update this part of the formula accordingly. Note the table made here is not elegant as it repeats values like 'Class' and '# of students' but it will not matter as move to step 2.
2. Use `Query` to ingest the table created in step 1 and then filter the results of # of students for the Grade mentioned in `I2` and the 'Class' mentioned in `J2`.

Comment: Thanks! this really solves it. 1) I wonder if there is a pure `lookup` solution since in the end, it will return only one value. 2) I see that it is more efficient to join all tables in one table as I mentioned, but in that case, is there a function to split that long table back to three tables?

Comment: Could you elaborate? This formula also returns only one value.

Comment: Yes. It's not a big deal, but I just thought that `query` is supposed to be used to yield tables, and `lookup` is used to get single results. So maybe `lookup` has a way to support multi-keys. But never mind. Point (2) is the crux of this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand point 2 as well. Why are you looking at splitting the long table back? You will already have them in the sheet and can keep adding data to them. Could you explain this further?

Comment: Maybe it worth [a question on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962267/spreadsheet-table-wrapping).

Comment: My idea is to fully remove the 3 separated tables and replace them with one long table. Then hide this big table and write a function to convert it to 3 separate more readable tables.

Comment: Got it. You are right, that's a separate question. If the solution helped you achieve what you were asking in this questions then please [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I3; INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3;         MATCH(I2&""; REGEXEXTRACT(1:1; "\d+"); ))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A); MATCH(I2&""; REGEXEXTRACT(1:1; "\d+"); )+1)); 2; )))
```

[image]

---

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I3; INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3;         MATCH(H2&" "&I2; 1:1; ))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A); MATCH(H2&" "&I2; 1:1; )+1)); 2; )))
```

[image]

---

or different approach:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP("Grade "&I2&I3, 
 {FLATTEN(FILTER(A1:F1&A3:F100, MOD(COLUMN(A:F)-1, 2)=0)),
  FLATTEN(FILTER(A1:F1&A3:F100, MOD(COLUMN(A:F), 2)=0))}, 2, )))
```

[image]