# Spreadsheet table wrapping

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Given a long spreadsheet table, is there a function to wrap it (break it) into multiple column tables?

[image: input output sample]

---

## What I tried

```js
=query(dataTable, "select A, B limit "&floor(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5))
=query(dataTable, "select A, B offset "&floor(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5))
```

but maybe there is a better solution, especially that it is not flexible in the number of columns (e.g: I want the table to be distributed on 3 or 4 tables not 2).

One other problem is if the input table is created using query, and that query is changed to include additional columns, the cells where they include `=query(dataTable, "select ...` must be separated more to give space.

Comment: What criteria are you looking at to split the Input? Will it be always segmented into 2 tables or does that vary as well?

Comment: I want it to vary. That's why I mentioned in "What I tried" that "it is not flexible". I want it flexible by specifying how many split tables are.

Answer (score 1):

> especially that it is not flexible in the number of columns

you can skip the `select` like:

```
=QUERY(dataTable, "limit  "&FLOOR(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5))
=QUERY(dataTable, "offset "&FLOOR(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5))
```

> but maybe there is a better solution

you can use single formula:

```
={QUERY(dataTable, "limit  "&FLOOR(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5)),
  QUERY(dataTable, "offset "&FLOOR(ROWS(dataTable)*0.5))}
```

just make sure total rows are divisible by 2

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT({REPT(TEXTJOIN(, 1, A1:D1&"×"), F1); 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(F1, ROUNDUP(MAX(IF(A:A="",,ROW(A:A)))/F1))), 
 {ROW(A2:A)-1, FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:D="", "♀×", A2:D&"×")),,9^9))}, 
 2, ))),,9^9))}, "×", 1, )), "♀", ))
```

[image]

#### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/105EwsaQ_z7uZGwQ6DIQ1MoB8yjqYT39qSO_txFwXIAQ/copy)

Comment: I meant by "it is not flexible" that it is only split into two tables. Is it possible to modify the formula to accept `n` as the number of tables to split?

Comment: @AvidSeeker that would be possible I guess. whats the upper limit for n? can you share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: The values are copied from [List of national capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals). `n` can be 3 to 5, but let's say that the upper limit is 7.