# google sheet : split the long data output - from single column into multiple column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a big sheet with lot of data. I extract a column from that sheet with certain condition using filter() or query() or vlookup(). Then the result will be a single column with long data/row. For example : the output is a single column with 300 rows but i want 50 row per column. Is there any method split them automatically into 6 column (each contains 50 rows) rather than having a single column contains 300 rows.

Thanks

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962267/spreadsheet-table-wrapping) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### An Apps Script solution

While this may be possible with formulae, even [player0's brilliant and complex function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962267/spreadsheet-table-wrapping) has an upper limit to how much input it can handle. To me it seems like a perfect situation for an Apps Script custom function.

```js
function divideColumn(input, numberToSplit){
  const length = input.length
  // The input it receives in the form of a two dimensional array. This just makes it one dimensional for convenience
  const flattenedInput = input.flat()
  // Getting the number of columns that will be filled
  const numberOfColumns = Math.ceil(length / 50)

  // Building the 2D array output with the specified number of rows.
  const output = []
  for (let i=0; i!= numberToSplit; i++){
    output.push([])
  }

  // Building an intermediate 2D array of the columns
  const columns = []

  for (let j=0; j!=numberOfColumns; j++){
    const lowerBound = numberToSplit * j
    let upperBound;
    if (j != numberOfColumns - 1) {
      upperBound = numberToSplit * (j + 1)
    } else {
      upperBound = -1
    }
    const col = flattenedInput.slice(lowerBound, upperBound)
    columns.push(col)
  }

  // Transposing the intermediate array into the final output format
  columns.forEach((col) => {
    col.forEach((val, idx) => {
      output[idx].push(val)
    })
  })

  return output
}
```

In use you can do this:

[image]

#### Limitation

It will only work with a single column.

#### Installation instructions

Menu > Tools > Script Editor

Past the function there and save.

Then you should be ready to go!

#### Reference

- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)